# No such file or Directory error for including header file C

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, header-files

I am trying to include a header file which contains a structure, but when I try to compile the file including the header file, I get `No such file or Directory` error. Both `.c` and header file are in the same directory.

Here is the code:

Header file "MyShared.h":

```
#ifndef MYSHARED_H_INCLUDED
    #define MYSHARED_H_INCLUDED
    #define PERM (S_IRWRU | S_IRGRP)
    #define MySharedKey 0343
    #define SIZE 2048

    struct MyShared
    {
        char *buf[SIZE];
        int ReadfromBuf,WriteToBuf,readbytes;
    };
#endif
```

`Mem.c` file including the header file:

```
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include "MyShared.h"

int main()
{
    MyShared *obj;

    int shmid,i,childpid;

    shmid = shmget(MySharedKey,sizeof(MyShared),NULL);

    .....
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please add the exact error to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a struct definition is **not** a typedef.

```
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include "MyShared.h"


int main()
{
struct MyShared *obj;

int shmid,i,childpid;

shmid=shmget(MySharedKey, sizeof *obj, NULL);

    .....
}
```

BTW: I don't think you want an array of *pointers* in shared memory: `char *buf[SIZE];`
 should probably be `char buf[SIZE];`

Comment: @Alfred Now I'm baffled. While wildplasser's points are good, they have absolutely nothing to do with the compiler not finding a header. So what was the problem with that?

Comment: @DanielFischer: me too. But I only started reading the text **after** spotting the usual suspects ...